# Combine multiple text rows with identical column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to combine rows with 1 column being the same and the rest is of type `nvarchar`.

TempTable

```
Id | Key          | Description1 | Description2
 1 | 60287F58-4631| Lorem Ipsum  | dolor sit amet
 2 | 60287F58-4631| consectetur  | adipiscing elit
 3 | 74553234-7543| Test test    | test test
```

I need to get this result:

```
Key          | DescriptionCombined
60287F58-4631| Lorem Ipsum, dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipiscing elit
74553234-7543| Test test, test test
```

I know that `group by` will not work because `Description1` and `Description2` are different between common rows. I started experimenting with `for xml path('')`, but this combines every row. I guess I need to first extract groups with the same key and then apply `for xml path('')`, but I cannot get this to work.

```
select ',' + t1.Description1, t1.Description2 from TempTable t1
for xml path('')
```

Comment: Can there be more than 2 repititions of the Key?

Comment: @Vashi Yes, there can be many more repetitions, but there are also records with no repetition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use subquery with `FOR XML PATH('')`

```
SELECT
    [Key],
    STUFF(
        (
            SELECT ', '+Description1+', '+Description2
            FROM TempTable t2
            WHERE t2.[Key]=t1.[Key]
            ORDER BY t2.Id
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1,2,'') DescriptionCombined
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Key] FROM TempTable) t1
```

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't figure out how to get the outer query to work.

Answer (score 0):

YOU Can Achive This Using STUFF Function In CTE

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (ID INT,[KEY] NVARCHAR(50),Description1 NVARCHAR(50),Description2 NVARCHAR(50))



INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT  1,'60287F58-4631','Lorem Ipsum','dolor sit amet'   UNION ALL
SELECT  2,'60287F58-4631','consectetur','adipiscing elit'  UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'74553234-7543','Test test','test test'

;WITH CTE
AS
    (   SELECT       [Key],
                    STUFF(
                        (
                            SELECT ', '+Description1+', '+Description2
                            FROM #TEMP a
                            WHERE a.[Key]=b.[Key]
                            ORDER BY a.Id
                            FOR XML PATH('')
                        ),1,2,'') DescriptionCombined
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Key] FROM #TEMP) b
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Comment: Thank you, but Leran2002 was a bit faster and posted similar answer :)

Comment: @Alfaiz Ahmed - It looks like on my answer. You only added `WITH` which is not needed here.

Comment: @Leran2002 it's Not Like That you Had Just Posted The Result when I was editing my Post Answer

Comment: @Alfaiz Ahmed - Ok. Sorry, if I was mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OUTER APPLY`

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE(Id INT,  [Key]  VARCHAR(20), Description1  VARCHAR(20) , Description2  VARCHAR(20) )
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES
( 1 ,'60287F58-4631', 'Lorem Ipsum',  'dolor sit amet'),
( 2 ,'60287F58-4631', 'consectetur',  'adipiscing elit'),
( 3 ,'74553234-7543', 'Test test',    'test test')

select [Key], MAX(STUFF(X.DescriptionCombined,1,1,'')) DescriptionCombined
    FROM @TempTable T1
    OUTER APPLY ( SELECT ', ' + Description1 +', '+ Description2 
                    FROM @TempTable T2 WHERE T1.[Key] = T2.[Key] FOR XML PATH('') ) X ( DescriptionCombined )
GROUP BY [Key]
```

Result:

```
Key                  DescriptionCombined
-------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
60287F58-4631         Lorem Ipsum, dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipiscing elit
74553234-7543         Test test, test test
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun - approach with recursive CTE:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  TOP 1 WITH TIES id, 
            [Key],
            CAST(CONCAT(Description1,', ',Description2)  as nvarchar(max))as DescriptionCombined,
            1 as lev
    FROM YourTable y
    ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Key] ORDER BY id ASC)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  y.id,   
            c.[Key],
            CAST(CONCAT(c.DescriptionCombined,', ',Description1,', ',Description2)  as nvarchar(max))as DescriptionCombined,
            lev+1
    FROM YourTable y
    INNER JOIN cte c
        ON y.[Key] = c.[key] AND y.[id] > c.[id]
)


SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES  [Key],
                        DescriptionCombined
FROM cte
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Key] ORDER BY lev DESC)
```

Output:

```
Key             DescriptionCombined
60287F58-4631   Lorem Ipsum, dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipiscing elit
74553234-7543   Test test, test test
```